# Pre-processing to inject log statements with minor visibility in source code

Tags: git, logging, editor, ada, gnat

I'm working with extensive logging for years now.
My question is not about logging versus debugging
but an argument which comes again and again.

It is simply ugly to have excessive log statements
disturbing the reader looking for function flow.

There is no value to see the log statements. Only
by reviewing the recorded logs they are needed.

Even pre-processor usage will not help enough.

My idea is to put it into comments where all editors
help to reduce the visibility (e.g. light gray).

Today I'm working on an Ada/gnat project but this
isn't important. Here a simple example

```
<code>
...
i := i + 1;   --@123.345@
...

<mapping file>
--@123.345@
if logging_enabled then 
  put_line("i: " & Integer'image(i));
end if;
--@123.678@
...
```

By going through pre-processing the code should be inline
modified to give the mapped block within the same line
to the compiler (no line feeds). The line count of the file 
will not increase.

It is not clear to me if this could be done without affecting
incremental compilation (time stamps issues).  Only the compile
step sees the patched file. Later and for the repository (git)
this shouldn't be notified.

Any comments which trouble I have to expect? Is there a similar
example available to see how the compilation can be manipulated
this way.

thanks
Wolfgang R.

Comment: See also [*NetBeans: Code Folding*](https://ui.netbeans.org/docs/ui/code_folding/cf_uispec.html).

Comment: Thanks for this point. I wasn't aware that custom folding did enhance so much over the last years. Have to check if all the IDEs involved will cope with it.

Comment: A now fallow Ada plugin worked with folding; NetBeans uses the feature to fold IDE generated code; you might be able to incorporate folds usefully in [templates](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-filetemplates.html).

Comment: As always in the Ada world we have some lecacy stuff in the back. For the next time GPS is still our IDE which I assume will not give us the latest features like Netbeans or Eclipse. Of course the custom folding would be the correct solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using GPS, you could try using the plugin gps_utils.highlighter

```
from ps_utils.highligher import *
Regexp_Highlighter(
   regexp='if logging_enabled.*end if',
   style=OverlayStyle(
      foreground='gray'
   )
)
```

You will likely have to play a bit with things to get it right, but that should allow you to simply highlight (or as the case may be the opposite) specific parts of the code

Comment: Thanks for this input too. Additional to the discussion with trashgod above there is a drawback to IDE stuff. I assume that this custom folding/highlighting isn't standardized. That means I lock my sources to a specific IDE. That's at least an issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got it. I need a second build directory.

The primary doesn't have any logging code. The second directory
is supervised by a controller process. If it gets a signal
(e.g. updated executable) from the primary it copies over
the touched sources and patches in the logging statements.

The controller process finally starts the incremental build
in the secondary.

This way both worlds are fairly separated. Doubling the
compilations won't matter I guess.